# Comparing values in different tables with SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm still new to SQLite and more specififcally SQL so please go easy on me.  I have three tables in my SQLite database that look something like this:

```
TableA
DateAdded  Data1  Data2
1/1/2012   a      b
1/3/2012   c      d
1/2/2012   e      f

TableB
DateAdded  Data3  Data4
1/6/2012   g      h
1/5/2012   i      j
1/4/2012   k      l

TableC
DateAdded  Data5  Data6
1/8/2012   m      n
1/9/2012   o      p
1/7/2012   q      r
```

Each table has a `DateAdded` column which is a `datetime` data type.  I want to get the most recent `datetime` value of all three tables.

Right now I do each table one at a time and compare the results:

```
private DateTime GetEndTime()
{
    DateTime retVal = new DateTime();
    DateTime sa = new DateTime();
    DateTime gps = new DateTime();

    SQLiteCommand cmd = mySQL.CreateCMD();
    SQLiteDataReader dbReader = mySQL.ExecuteQuerySQL("SELECT DateAdded FROM DF ORDER BY ROWID DESC LIMIT 1", cmd);
    if (dbReader.HasRows)
    {
        dbReader.Read();
        retVal = dbReader.GetDateTime(0);
    }
    dbReader.Close();

    dbReader = mySQL.ExecuteQuerySQL("SELECT DateAdded FROM SA ORDER BY ROWID DESC LIMIT 1", cmd);
    if (dbReader.HasRows)
    {
        dbReader.Read();
        sa = dbReader.GetDateTime(0);
    }
    dbReader.Close();

    if (retVal < sa)
        retVal = sa;

    dbReader = mySQL.ExecuteQuerySQL("SELECT DateAdded FROM GPS ORDER BY ROWID DESC LIMIT 1", cmd);
    if (dbReader.HasRows)
    {
        dbReader.Read();
        gps = dbReader.GetDateTime(0);
    }
    dbReader.Close();
    mySQL.disposeCMD(cmd);

    if (retVal < gps)
        retVal = gps;

    return retVal;
}
```

I *know* there must be a better way.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could choose the Max DateAdded from each table, then union those rows and select the max, like so:

```
select MAX(MaxDateAdded) from
(
 select MAX(DateAdded) as MaxDateAdded from a 
 union
 select MAX(DateAdded) as MaxDateAdded from b
 union
 select MAX(DateAdded) as MaxDateAdded from c
) AS UnionedDateAddedTables
```

Comment: +1 Because this also gives me some ideas on how to economize other queries I have done.  Just one question, what is `UnionedDateAddedTables`?

Comment: The table alias for the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MAX(DateAdded)
FROM
(
SELECT MAX(DateAdded) AS DateAdded FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT MAX(DateAdded) AS DateAdded FROM tableb
UNION
SELECT MAX(DateAdded) AS DateAdded FROM tablec
)
```

**EDIT**:

I am replacing:

```
Instead of selecting all rows
```

With

```
SELECT MAX(DateAdded) AS DateAdded FROm table
```

thanks to @dugas

Comment: Will this have performance issues if the tables are very large?

Comment: It is possible this could have performance issues if any of the tables were large as it would union all records and then sort through the entire set to get the max.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the help.  Accepted the other answer because I suspect that the way they union just the dates will be more efficient.

Comment: Each table is completely non-related and represents completely different sets of information.  I was lazy and just showed each table with two columns in my example, but there are many many many columns.